# Django virtual environment wrapper

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I just started learning django and kept wondering, do I need to install a virtual environment wrapper everytime I want to start a project before creating the virtual environment? or is the virtual environment wrapper already installed in my system and I just have to go straight to creating the virtual environment?
These are the commands I used for creating my virtual environment

```
//creating the virtual environment wrapper
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
//creating a virtual environment called test
mkvirtualenv test
//installing django
pip install django
//creating my project folder
mkdir project
```

Answer (score 0):

for short project i think is not necessary .

> A virtual environment is a tool that helps to keep dependencies
>   required by different projects separate by creating isolated python
>   virtual environments for them.

but if i wanna answer your question : i should to say YES, every time you need to create this.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful